# Remove tags from the beginning and end of the string with PHP

Tags: php, string, tags

I need to get a string without the tags at the beginning and end of the string. I know `strip_tags` but as you know it removes all tags. For example:

```
<span class="note">
  <span></span>This is my text <strong>Hello world</strong> 
</span>
```

In this example i want to keep the `<strong>` tags. Important to know that i want a unconditional solution because the tags can be different. I know already that you can exclude tags with strip_tags (that is not what i want to know) but that is not the case.

Does anyone know a fast solution to this, for example a reg expression replace or something (the thing i am not good at). Cannot find such thing on the net so that's why i ask it here.

Thank you for the contribution.

Answer (score 3):

[DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) would be handy for this...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$html = '';

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->firstChild->childNodes as $node) {
    $html .= trim($dom->saveHTML($node));
}

echo $html;
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tSFWE5).

If you were unswayable about using a regex, you could use...

```
$html = preg_replace('/^\s*<[^>]+>\s*|\s*<\/[^>]+>\s*\z/', '', $html);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3lUqyN).

Note that a HTML tag with an attribute containing a `>` would fail the regex. That's why I'd prefer the DOMDocument solution.

Both these solutions will strip leading and trailing whitespace text nodes. If that is not desirable, drop the `trim()` from the first example and the `\s*` from the second example.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I cannot use the DOMDocument because the document is already loaded and i don't want to load it twice (memory) but maybe i can use it to parse a snippet. Also the reg expression is working fine except when you add an empty tag (for example <span></span>) before it. It is no problem that it is not working when an attribute contains a '>', it is a way of bad coding. But, can you change it so that the an empty span also will be removed? Thank you so much!

Comment: Try changing `/^\s*<[^>]+>\s*|\s*<\/[^>]+>\s*\z/` with `/^\s*<[^>]+>|<\/[^>]+>\s*\z/` and I think you'll get the desired result? :)

Comment: Already loaded in memory by template system and done allot stuff with it. This will be a part of auto translate a document to another language.

Comment: You should be getting `<span></span>This is my text <strong>Hello world</strong>` ; http://codepad.viper-7.com/EO7NhE

Comment: Yes i know, but want also the <span></span> removed.... Only the string with tags in it. When a string is started every tag before and after the actual string must be removed...

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a simple function, rather than calling DOM classes - they run slower.
This is what I usually do: http://codepad.viper-7.com/RVKmAG

Comment: Thanks, but is not what i want, it seems that it do the same as strip_tags because the var_dump is totally without any tag.